# Navigate from one fragment to another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I spend last two days surf in web looking for a solution for next problem:
I have an adapter class inside a tab in ViewPager I try to call a fragment in on click event using fragment manager. When the fragment is call all is ok, but when i try to go back the previous tab in the last position is no showed, instead of that the main activity is showed.

in adapter:

```
FragmentManager fm = ((MainActivity) v.getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.root, fragment)
                        .addToBackStack(null);
                ft.commit();
```

In fragment

```
getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
```

for return to previous fragment but not work for me, Only redirect pfor main activity

Comment: Please share some code so that we have a better idea of what you've attempted and what could possibly be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using viewpager inside the fragment then use fragment's childFragmentManager instead of fragmentManager.

Fragment Class:

```
adapterViewPager = new MyPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
vpPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);
```

Adapter Class:

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private static int NUM_ITEMS = 3;

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
            super(fragmentManager);
        }

        // Returns total number of pages
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_ITEMS;
        }

        // Returns the fragment to display for that page
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
            case 0: // Fragment # 0 - This will show FirstFragment
                return FirstFragment.newInstance(0, "Page # 1");
            case 1: // Fragment # 0 - This will show FirstFragment different title
                return FirstFragment.newInstance(1, "Page # 2");
            case 2: // Fragment # 1 - This will show SecondFragment
                return SecondFragment.newInstance(2, "Page # 3");
            default:
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Returns the page title for the top indicator
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return "Page " + position;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though the fragments aren't being added to `backstack`. Assuming you're using FragmentTransaction, add this line of code along with the other code to swap fragments:

```
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean to say, how to load previous fragment instead of an Activity? If this is your requirement, then do following in onBackPressed() method, if you are adding fragment in back stack:

```
onBackPressed() {
     super.onBackPressed();
     getActivity().getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Android OS provide back stack function for Activity, it also provide back stack function for Fragment. If you add one Fragment into back stack, when you press the android device back menu, you can find the Fragment that is saved in back stack popup. Until all saved Fragments in back stack popup, then the activity will exit.

```
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(true);
```